Standard layout unions with common initial sequence to create checked-bitfields as drop in replacements for bitfields?
Given class.mem/28:
https://eel.is/c++draft/class.mem#general-28
Which states:

In a standard-layout union with an active member of struct type T1, it
is permitted to read a non-static data member m of another union
member of struct type T2 provided m is part of the common initial
sequence of T1 and T2; the behavior is as if the corresponding member
of T1 were nominated.

I think its valid to create a union with multiple (different) structs each with a uint64_t member:
template<some params>
struct CustomField
{
    void operator=(uint64_t newVal)
    {
        val = someCustomInsertFn(newVal);
    }

    operator uint64_t() const
    {
        return someCustomExtractFn(val);
    }

    uint64_t val; // Note that this is used in a union and so aliases with all other fields and the `all` below
};

Then:
union CheckedBitField
{
    struct { uint64_t all; }
    CustomField<some param> fieldOne;
    CustomField<some other param> fieldTwo;
};

The idea being this is a simple union with structure members each of which just has a uint64_t val.
But those custom fields have custom void operator=(uint64_t newVal) and operator uint64_t() const operators which can add additional checks over what you can get with a basic bitfield.
An example of the insert function is to add additional checks that the value you are writing is logically valid and/or wont be truncated.
So this code is valid - just like in a normal bitfield:
CheckedBitField b{};
b.fieldOne = 5; // This runs custom code.

Does adding those additional functions break the class.mem/28 rules and/or am I missing something?
Full runnable code - which adds the functionality to set the min/max value of a field:
https://godbolt.org/z/ozz16GEP8

The quoted text says "read a non-static data member", nothing about writing a non-static data member, or about calling a member function (both of which your code does),, so I believe that section does not apply at all.  Furthermore basic.life describes all the ways that a union member may have its lifetime started, and your case is none of those (class.union/5 is the most obvious one which may apply, but it covers only built-in or trivial assignment operators)

@user2407038 Writing is ok from what I can see - I read the current value from the fields specific unit64_t  (so is ok according to the rules) and then write the version in that field (so setting a new active slot but the active one doesn't matter as the next operation will be a read) - this is done in the member function. The member function being called is yes what I'm worried about.

Since this is language lawyer, before the line b.fieldOne = 5; there is no active member of the union. The rules in class.union/5 which describe how a union member may become active do not apply here, therefore, fieldOne is not the active member, and so its lifetime has not begun. Accessing an object outside of its lifetime is UB. class.mem/28 specifically mentions "read data member" and what you are doing is a member function call, so it does not apply.

So you are saying that calling a member-function on a non-active member is UB? Interesting.

Yes, only the active union member is within its lifetime. You can do very little with objects outside their lifetime - here calling a member function of an object outside its lifetime is explicitly listed as UB

b.fieldOne = 5; has undefined behavior already before anything in your quote could become relevant.
The fieldOne member is not active, therefore the corresponding member subobject is not in its lifetime and calling a non-static member function on it is therefore UB.
The assignment also won't start the lifetime and make the member active because = is neither the built-in operator nor a trivial assignment operator in this case. (That's the only exception where new or a function that implicitly creates objects isn't needed to change the active member of a union.)
And also, the quote specifically is about reading the inactive members, not writing to them, which is still UB regardless of whether the rule applies.
